# Owl Carousel conflicts with my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

Whenever I have 2 Owl-Carousel's on 1 site my hamburger menu doesn't work anymore.

I used [flew](https://freehtml5.co/p-preview/?item=flew-free-html5-bootstrap-template) as the base for my website. It uses jQuery v2.1.4.

Header HTML:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top affix" role="banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header-inner">
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Owl Carousel HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="container"> <!-- Owl Carousel 1 -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="owl-carousel-one">
                <div> <!-- content --> </div>
                <div> <!-- content --> </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="container"> <!-- Owl Carousel 2 -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="owl-carousel-two">
                <div> <!-- content --> </div>
                <div> <!-- content --> </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Hamburger menu / Header JS:

```
;(function () {
var mobileMenuOutsideClick = function() {

    $(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#tsj-offcanvas, .js-tsj-nav-toggle");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

        if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-visible') ) {

            $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-visible');
            $('.js-tsj-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');

        }


    }
    });

};


var offcanvasMenu = function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="tsj-offcanvas" />');
    $('#tsj-offcanvas').prepend('<ul id="tsj-side-links">');
    $('body').prepend('<a href="#" class="js-tsj-nav-toggle tsj-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>');
    $('#tsj-offcanvas').append($('#tsj-header nav').clone());
};


var burgerMenu = function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.js-tsj-nav-toggle', function(event){
        var $this = $(this);

        $('body').toggleClass('tsj-overflow offcanvas-visible');
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-visible') ) {
        $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-visible');
        $('.js-tsj-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
       }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas-visible') ) {
        $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-visible');
        $('.js-tsj-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
       }
    });
};
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

Owl Carousel (it's in the same function as the Hamburger menu / Header):

```
;(function () {

var oneCarousel = function(){
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel-one');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        autoHeight:true,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
            },
            1000:{
                items:1,
                nav:false,
                dots: true,
            }
        }
    });
};


$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight();
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    oneCarousel();
});


var twoCarousel = function(){
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel-two');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        autoHeight:false,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
            },
            1000:{
                items:1,
                nav:false,
                dots: true,
            }
        }
    });
};


$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight();
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    twoCarousel();
});

}());
```

Also this is the error message I receive when I click on the hamburger menu:

```
main.js:249 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:249)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

EDIT: Whenever I delete 1 Carousel (doesn't matter which one), my hamburger menu works again.

Comment: And which line in the code you posted is line 249?

Comment: I'm guessing that `this.hash` doesn't reference a valid DOM element, and these two lines are actually referencing "nothing": `var target = this.hash; var $target = $(target);`.  I'd suggest adding immediately afterwards `if ( ! $target.length ) { console.log(target + ' does not exist!'); return;}` and see what that does for you.

Comment: maybe is it because you are launching twice certain functions in your duplicate `$(function(){` functions? Like `burgerMenu();` for example?

Comment: @cale_b line 249 = 'scrollTop': $target.offset().top

Comment: @cale_b

if ( ! $target.length ) { console.log(target + ' does not exist!'); return;} didn't worked

Comment: @Kaddath I deleted the first function and added oneCarousel(); to the second function. Still doesn't work BUT the hover animation ist back

Comment: "Didn't work" is useless.  Did it display anything in your console?

Comment: @cale_b sorry about that, my website displayed me a blank page and gave me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

You have to add the "owl-carousel" class on your carousels.

```
<div>
<div class="container"> <!-- Owl Carousel 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-one">
            <div> <!-- content --> </div>
            <div> <!-- content --> </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="container"> <!-- Owl Carousel 2 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-two">
            <div> <!-- content --> </div>
            <div> <!-- content --> </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**AND** I made the mistake of launching the same function twice.

```
$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight();
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    oneCarousel();
});

$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight();
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    twoCarousel();
});
```

You need to fuse them:

```
$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight();
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    oneCarousel();
    twoCarousel();
});
```